# how to set select="selected " get by request attribute

Tags: javascript, jsp

HI All I want display the city(drop down box) value get by the request attribute in jsp..

 here city is drop down list .. I want to set select="selected" fro particular city based on the request value .. how can I set either by JSP or Javascript ?

Comment: At the very least you could show minimal markup of the select element and a bit of code that you've tried… in HTML the selected attribute has no value, it's boolean so it just is or isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a technique using Expression Language in a JSP.

```
        <select name="color">
            <option color="red" ${param.color eq 'red' ? 'selected' : ''}>Red</option>
            <option color="green" ${param.color eq 'green' ? 'selected' : ''}>Green</option>
            <option color="blue" ${param.color eq 'blue' ? 'selected' : ''}>Blue</option>
        </select>
```

**I do not like this solution**, but it is simple to write here. I would not use this solution in a large site.

Another solution is to set the values in a map using Java, then access the value in the JSP.

Include this code in the JSP:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" import="java.util.Map,java.util.HashMap"%>
<%
   Map<String, String> sport = new HashMap<String, String>();
   sport.put(request.getParameter("sport"), "selected");
   request.setAttribute("sport", sport);
%>
```

Write the select group as:

```
        <select name="sport">
            <option value="nfl" ${sport.nfl}>NFL</option>
            <option value="nba" ${sport.nba}>NBA</option>
            <option value="mlb" ${sport.mlb}>MLB</option>
        </select>
```

**I prefer to create simple JSPs that do not contain Java code.** The best solution is to use a servlet behind the JSP and move all the Java code to the servlet, leaving the JSP very simple. The above code could be refactored and be split between the servlet and the JSP.

This idea could be extended to handle multiple selection lists. It would be useful to create a larger map, named selected, that contains all the smaller maps for all the select groups.

```
    Map<String, String> toppings = new HashMap<String, String>();
    if (request.getParameterMap().get("toppings") != null) {
        for (String value : request.getParameterMap().get("toppings")) {
            toppings.put(value, "selected");
        }
    }

    Map<String, Map<String, String>> selected = new HashMap<String,
       Map<String, String>>();
    selected.put("toppings", toppings);
    selected.put("sport", sport);
    request.setAttribute("selected", selected);
```

The select groups would be modified to access the selected map first, then the group map.

```
        <select name="toppings" multiple>
            <option value="sprinkles" ${selected.toppings.sprinkles}>Sprinkles</option>
            <option value="fudge" ${selected.toppings.fudge}>Fudge</option>
            <option value="snickers" ${selected.toppings.snickers}>Snickers</option>
        </select>

        <select name="sport">
            <option value="nfl" ${selected.sport.nfl}>NFL</option>
            <option value="nba" ${selected.sport.nba}>NBA</option>
            <option value="mlb" ${selected.sport.mlb}>MLB</option>
        </select>
```

This could be extended even further so that the selected map is filled automatically, but that requires a bean and annotations.

Answer (score 0):

Hers is the code to set selected value using jquery

```
$("document").ready(function(){
    //say you have got 555 from the JSP as selcted value
    var selValue = "555";
    $("#selectnumber").val(selValue).attr("selected","selected")   
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ksx9323r/1/

Hope you are expecting the same
cheers

Comment: 'cos there's a jQuery tag and the OP has jQuery code… not. Dunno what *attr* does these days, it used to be broken. Setting the selected attribute doesn't necessarily select the option, setting the selected property does, always.

Answer (score 0):

As @petdowneyt's answer, this worked for me:

Code in jsp file:

```
<select name="operator" >
  <option value="ADD" ${operator eq 'ADD' ? 'selected' : ''}>+</option>
  <option value="SUBTRACT" ${operator eq 'SUBTRACT' ? 'selected' : ''}>-</option>
  <option value="MULTIPLY" ${operator eq 'MULTIPLY' ? 'selected' : ''}>X</option>
  <option value="DIVIDE" ${operator eq 'DIVIDE' ? 'selected' : ''}>/</option>           
</select>
```

Code in Servlet:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
String op = request.getParameter("operator");
session.setAttribute("operator", op);
```